# Abstract @property - instantiating a "partially implemented" class?

Tags: python, inheritance, abstract-class, python-decorators

I read [this](https://pymotw.com/3/abc/) very nice documentation on abstract class `abc.ABC`. It has this example (shortened by me for the purpose of this question):

```
import abc

class Base(abc.ABC):
    @property
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def value(self):
        return 'Should never reach here'

    @value.setter
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def value(self, new_value):
        return

class PartialImplementation(Base):  # setter not defined/overridden
    @property
    def value(self):
        return 'Read-only'
```

To my biggest surprise, `PartialImplementation` can be instantiated though it only overrides the getter:

```
>>> PartialImplementation()
<__main__.PartialImplementation at 0x7fadf4901f60>
```

Naively, I would have thought that since the interface has two abstract methods both would have to be overridden in any concrete class, which is what is written in the documentation: "Although a concrete class must provide implementations of all abstract methods,...". The resolution must be in that we actually have only one abstract name, `value`, that needs to be implemented and that does happen in `PartialImplementation`.

Can someone please explain this to me properly?

Also, why would you want to lift the setter to the interface if you are not required to implement it; current implementation does nothing if at all callable on a `PartialImplementation` instance.

Comment: *The resolution must be in that we actually have only one abstract name, `value`, that needs to be implemented and that does happen in `PartialImplementation`.* Yes, exactly this.

Comment: The documentation you linked to explains it quite well, since the part you removed creates a second subclass with a read-write property *from the same base class*. I suppose if you don't require that flexibility, you could simply rename the setter to something other than `value` to enforce a read-write implementation.

Comment: Logically speaking, every property has a setter; the default simply raises an exception. See the [pure Python definition of `property`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#properties) in the Descriptor How-To. You aren't just overriding the inherited getter in your base class; you are defining a *new* property with a concrete getter *and* setter.

Comment: @ekhumoro I deliberately removed the read-write case, `Implementation(Base)`, as that class behaved exactly as I expected: could be instantiated and both getter and setter work. As a matter of fact, with my limited Python knowledge, I would have only added the setter to that class (being a read-write class) and would have left it out from `Base`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR `PartialImplementation` is *not* partially implemented; you defined a *new* property with a concrete getter and a (logically) concrete setter, instead of supplying *only* a concrete getter.

---

Abstract properties are tricky. Your base class has *one* property, which defines *itself* as abstract by the presence of the abstract getter and setter, rather than a property that you explicitly defined as abstract.

`ABCMeta` determines if a class is abstract by looking for class
attributes with a `__isabstractmethod__` attribute set to `True`. `Base.value` is such an attribute. `PartialImplementation.value` is *not*, because its `value` attribute is a brand new property independent of `Base.value`, and it consists solely of a concrete getter.

Instead, you need to create a new property that's *based on* the inherited property, using the appropriate method supplied by the inherited property.

This class is still abstract, because `@Base.value.getter` creates
a property with a concrete getter but retaining the original abstract setter.

```
class PartialImplementation(Base):
    @Base.value.getter
    def value(self):
        return 'Read-only'
```

This class is concrete and *also* supplies a read-only property.

```
class PartialImplementation(Base):
    @Base.value.getter
    def value(self):
        return 'Read-only'

    @value.setter
    def value(self, v):
        # Following the example of the __set__ method
        # described in https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#properties
        raise AttributeError("property 'value' has no setter")
```

Note that if we used `Base.value.setter` instead of `value.setter`, we would have create a new property that *only* added a concrete setter to the inherited property (which still only has an abstract getter). We want to add the setter to our new property with a concrete getter.

(Also note that while `value.setter` can take `None` as an argument to "remove" an existing setter, it is not sufficient to override an abstract setter.)

---

I highly recommend looking at the pure-Python implemeantion of `property` in the [Descriptor Guide](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#properties) to see how properties work under the hood, and to understand why such care must be taken when trying to manipulate them.

One thing it lacks, though, is the code that manipulates the `__isabstractmethod__` attribute to make `@property` stackable with `@abstractmethod`. Essentially, it would set `__isabstractmethod__` on itself if any of its initial components were abstract, and each of `getter`, `setter`, and `deleter` set the attribute to false if the *last* abstract component were replaced with a concrete one.

Comment: Whew - this took a lot of experimenting  to get right, as I dispelled one mistaken belief after another that I had about how abstract properties worked. Hopefully, I've at least not said anything wrong in the above.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I am glad you also learned from this. I admit I will have to read this a few more times to let it sink in, with my current Python knowledge, but I did understand this: "ABCMeta determines if a class is abstract by looking for class attributes with a __isabstractmethod__ attribute set to True. Base.value is such an attribute. PartialImplementation.value is not, because its value attribute is a brand new property independent of Base.value, and it consists solely of a concrete getter."